# Maintaining old Fortran code - tends to do SUBROUTINE stuff(x,y), x = x, y = y

Tags: fortran

One of the things I've been tasked with at work is maintaining old Fortran code.  I'm an analyst, and I generally understand the problem the code is solving, but I'm struggling a bit with some of the bits of code.

To give you an idea of the era the code was written in, it makes reference to Grumman Data Systems's TS/RJE service, which connected an IBM 360/67 and a 360/75.  Late 1960's era.  The code itself still has a few arithmetic IF's, no block IF's, lots of GOTOs...

Anyway, one of the quirks I've seen a lot of is, the inputs to a subroutine will be set equal to themselves in the first few lines of code.  Like,

```
SUBROUTINE STUFF(X,Y)
X = X
Y = Y
X = X + Y
RETURN
END
```

Any insights on why they'd be doing that?  The best I can figure is that, maybe in case an input isn't specified, it would set it to 0.  But I don't know enough about my compiler, or the compiler they were using back in the day, to say whether that would be necessary/effective.

Comment: It shouldn't set anything to zero.

Comment: Was it used with Fortran G/H or some other compiler? You may find more old guys at comp.lang.fortran.

Comment: I couldn't say what the code was written to be compiled with.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The comp.lang.fortran thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/0chOCcCBETI

Comment: I used a product called PlusFort (from the UK) to undo the computed GOTOs and other restructuring. It is pretty food for a first crack, but still requires some effort. What is really required is to have some test cases to work out knowing whether the restructuring is giving the expected answers.

Is it possible that the X = X was envisioned to do something like ensuring that the value was from the HEAP rather than from a register? This is more of a total-guess than fact.

Comment: I often (in the past) have had (Xin, Yin) and then X=Xin...

I cannot envision any other thing unless it was a start at making X,Y INTENT(IN) and moving the result to be a function call... But then the approach was forgotten to be completed.